# Mirror modifier on the same axis is actually opposite

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have joined two objects: the body, and arms, which i imported from another file, and I'm trying to connect them. Both have mirror modifier, that i would like to keep.  When i use bridge edge loops, the loops go to other side of the mesh.
[image: Meshes]

[image: weird connection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply both mirror modifiers, perfom the brdige edge loop operation on one side, then select and delete all the other side and re-add a mirror.